# Android Camera PictureCallback data seems corrupted on HTC Desire S

Tags: android

I'm using PictureCallback to capture an image. And its working fine. But In HTC Desire S its not returning proper data. It returns a corrupted image like the following one

[image]

Here is the code that i used

```
    PictureCallback cameraPictureCallbackJpeg = new PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                          FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                  try {
                // write to local sandbox file system
                // outStream =
                // CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg",
                // System.currentTimeMillis()), 0);
                // Or write to sdcard
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                        "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                Log.e("error", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
    }
```

I must tell you that I've used other methods to convert the data into a bitmap. Thanks in advance. I'm stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not using one of the supported image sizes.
Here is how you can get those.

```
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List<size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

EDIT: This is how you set the picture size:

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.setPictureSize(int width, int height);
try {
camera.setParameters(params);
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e(TAG, "set parameters failed");
}
```

Comment: Even if image size is advertised as "supported" sometimes it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody promissed you that picture format will be the same on different devices. You have to pay attention to camera settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know its not same in different devices. But I need the solution urgent.

Comment: If I were you, I would dump all current camera settings and  available parameters - and then look how to configure it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. So, up vote is for you. But norbert was specific. So I accepted his answer.